# Inference on latent variable with observation of its convolution with itself

Tags: convolution, latent-variable, dirichlet-process, stable-distribution

### Problem

I have an inference problem where the data observed are univariate random numbers whose distribution is obtained as follows. A latent random variable X is first sampled from a  parametric distributions.

\begin{equation}
\theta \sim \pi
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
X \mid \theta \sim p_1(x \mid \theta)
\end{equation}
and the data distribution for the data $d$ is obtained by the convolution of $p_1$ with itself, i.e. by summing realizations of $X$ with themselves.
\begin{equation}
d \mid \theta \sim p_2(\cdot \mid \theta) = p_1(\cdot \mid \theta) * p_1(\cdot \mid \theta) 
\end{equation}
where $*$ denotes the convolution of the $p_1$ with itself, and observations of $Y$ are available.
\begin{equation}
p_2(x\mid \theta) = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \mathrm{d}y p_1(y \mid \theta)p_1(x-y \mid \theta)
\end{equation}

### Inference problem

I would like to perform inference on the parameters $\theta$ of $p_1$, though for various reasons most approaches do not seem suitable.

Here are my findings:

- Normalizing flows on $p_1$ cannot be used as they require an invertible transformation between $p_2$ and $p_1$
- Non-parametric methods, e.g. Dirichlet processes, are not very flexible upon convolution. Convolving samples of a $DP$ with itself lead to a process with complicated weights
- Stable distributions are a good pick because of their closedness upon convolution, but they are too limited to reconstruct the data I observe.

Are there other approaches one usually follows? It is in my opinion quite a generic statistical problem, and I'd be surprised if there are not results on this topic.